# Firemail delivered html newsletter showing source code to end client

Tags: ee2, email, newsletter

I have firemail installed on the ee with the mailgun to deliver the newsltters. When i send the newsletters using the email templates, all the emails shows the html source code instead of rendering it.

Comment: Control Panel: Admin > Email Configuration > Default Mail Format?

Comment: What version of Firemail are you using.  What version of EE?

Comment: Admin > Email Configuration > Default Mail Format already set to HTML

Comment: EE :: 2.10.1
Firemail :: 1.9.3